# Wordpress Get Posts from each category equally

Tags: categories

I have posts which have `private` status for now. I want to assign them random date by selecting of categories.

I did code like this

```
$begin = new DateTime( $_POST['start_date'] );  
$end   = new DateTime( $_POST['end_date'] );    
for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i->modify('+7 day'))
{       
    $rdate[] = $i->format("Y-m-d"); 
}

$total_no_of_dates = count($rdate);

$posts = get_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => $total_no_of_dates, 'category__in' => $cats_ids,  'orderby' => 'rand', 'post_status' => array('publish', 'pending', 'draft', 'future', 'private'), 'post_type' => 'post', 'date_query' => array('after' => array('year'  => 5000,'month' => 1,'day'   => 1,),)));
```

But it fetches posts from array categories, I want all categories posts for example I want to run loop from that category first which lowest no of posts. So that I can get from all categories almost equal posts.